# Install a more recent version of git on a LTS

Tags: 10.04, git

I can't upgrade my lucid lynx 10.04 LTS because newer distributions of ubuntu don't work on that computer. I need to install a git version 1.7.10 for credential management. Git version is 1.7.0.4 on 10.04 LTS:

```
$ dpkg -l *git*
+++-==============-==============-============================================
ii  git-core       1:1.7.0.4-1ubu fast, scalable, distributed revision control
```

Is there a way or a backport to install git 1.7.10 or newer ?

Comment: Actually if you can run 10.04 it is quite probable you can run Xubuntu or Lubuntu satisfactorily. Now, unless we are talking about the server edition of 10.04, it has been discontinued (reached End Of Life). If you are talking about the server edition it is still recommended to upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 at least.

Comment: The last versions I could find were http://ppa.launchpad.net/lucid-bleed/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/g/git/ (1.7.1) but I strongly recommend that you upgrade that computer to a newer version. It would also help to know what actually does not work on that computer with newer versions.

Comment: We have [a meta question for discussing whether or not questions that apply fully to supported Server systems are on-topic, even if they are asked about systems not explicitly stated to be servers (or even about desktop systems)](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7163/arent-ubuntu-server-end-of-life-versions-off-topic).

Comment: Git is a 5yr supported package. So questions regarding Git on 10.04 is perfectly **on-topic** I'd say. Voted to reopen. (cc @LuisAlvarado)

Comment: Opened again because of the supported time for the git packages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The PPA [`ppa:git-core/ppa`](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa) provides backports of the most current stable version of Git for various Ubuntu versions.

On the command line you can add the PPA using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
```

If you receive an error stating `add-apt-repository` was not found, install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Comment: I just did this and got `1.7.9.5` when the current version is `1.9.2`. Apparently that PPA is out of date.

Comment: What release are you on? It sure looks like it has 1.9.2 to me: https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa

Comment: as of today you get `2.31` on ppa and `2.24` on backports/normal. I think standard `backports` is not supported for git as apt install git/focal-backports is not found.